# Discord Py user mention in a message

Tags: python, discord.py

so I'm currently trying to have my discord bot receive a command with a mention, ping the mentioned person and say "shut up". The code runs but it pings the person, then says shut up. I need some help trying to make both of those parts into one message instead of 2.

```
async def quiet(ctx, user : discord.Member):
  await ctx.channel.send(user.mention)
  await ctx.channel.send("shut up")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`await ctx.channel.send(user.mention + "shut up")` should do it

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
async def quiet(ctx, user : discord.Member):
  message = user.mention + "shut up"
  await ctx.channel.send(message)
```

Let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the f string to do so while using curly brackets to cover the 'mention' part.

```
async def quiet(ctx, user : discord.Member):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{user.mention} shut up!")
```

can be used for pretty much anything for example:

in the image below, I use the following for my purge command if no number is specified:

```
if limit is None:  #limit is an argument here, that is amount of messages user wants to delete
      return await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Please specify the number of messages you want to delete!", delete_after = 3)  #this sends a message to specify the amount of message the user desires to delete while mentioning them (the author is the term for the person who triggered the command)
```

[image]

Comment: This is my personal favorite. I didn't know about f-strings for a while, I used to use `str.format` and concatenation until I found out they exist and it's my new favorite thing.